# Send data from raspberrypi to webserver

Tags: php, apache, arduino, raspberry-pi

my raspberry-pi is taking sensor readings from an Arduino  and storing them in the database ,
i want to send these database values to my website or either store it in a  database on the web can someone please  tell me how it can be done .
which language can i use or is PHP is OK for that

Comment: You might want to do some more research, and than ask more specific questions when you run into specific programming problems. What you want to do is quite common design wise and there should be quite a lot of material out there to study. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter which language you use, there are endless possibilities. Yes, you can do that with php on the server side. IN that case you need two things:

1. on the client side (raspi) you make an http(s) request to the server sending the data as request parameters (GET or POST). Easy tools for that are `wget` or `cURL`. You can use both utilities from within a script in whatever language you want to use on the raspi.
2. on the server you have your http server running a small php script for each such request which receives the data, make some plausibility checks (and possibly an authentication) and then stores the data into some database.

An alternative would be to expose the database server directly via internet and make the database query directly from the client (raspi). This requires less components but obviously offers less freedom too.

Comment: can you give some reference tutorial

Comment: Sorry, I know of no tutorial for such a specific task. You will have to look into the basic documentation of the tools involved: `wget` or `cURL` (see their man pages), php and its basic usage as a http server scripting language and obviously the mysql extension. For the second alternative all you need is a mysql client on the raspi. Check the mysql documentation, it contains examples. Obviously you can also use another database server beside mysql, it just has to be network enabled, so nothing like sqlite or BerkeleyDB.

Answer (score 1):

if the arduino is sending data by HTTP calls, then just take your PHP, and put it in a free web-service. Just remebrer to update your PHP to use your free-service database, and the arduino to point to your new site.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a personal project to answer this question.

Follow steps:

1. I created a free web hosting and free domain at [000webhost](https://www.000webhost.com/)

   This [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1iz0YlBl84&t=35s) can help you do everything needed for that (domain name creation, database creation, etc)
2. Server side program: This [Youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKH0Bx35N7U) may help too but I will put my own code here.

   ```
   file name: insert.php
   <?php

   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
   header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

   //Creating Array for JSON response
   $response = array();

   // Check if we got the field from the user
   //here, we're getting only one parameter(puissance) from raspberry
   if (isset($_POST['puissance'])) {

   // Include database connection
   // all your database credentials(hostname, dbname, usrname,...) should 
   //be written in db_connect.php 
   //file
   include_once 'db_connect.php';

   $puissance = $_POST['puissance'];
   date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Casablanca');
   $dt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


   // SQL query to insert data in sensorpower1
   $sql = "INSERT INTO sensorpower1(sensor_power, power_date) 
   VALUES('$puissance','$dt');";
   $result =  mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

   // Check for succesfull execution of query
   if ($result) {
   // successfully inserted 
   $response["success"] = 1;
   $response["message"] = "Puissance insérée avec succès.";

   // Show JSON response
   echo json_encode($response);
   } else {
   // Failed to insert data in database
   $response["success"] = 0;
   $response["message"] = "Une erreur s'est produite";

   // Show JSON response
   echo json_encode($response);
   }
   } else {
   // If required parameter is missing
   $response["success"] = 0;
   $response["message"] = "Paramètre manquant";

   // Show JSON response
   echo json_encode($response);
   }
   ?>
   ```

3.Python code in raspberry. The variable 'puissance' receive its value from arduino that is why you will see stuff like serial or readline in python code. I covered here only from raspberry to server part. See code

```
    import serial
    import requests
    import time

    ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0")
    ser.baudrate = 9600

    data = ser.readline()
    puissanceW = data

    adresse = 'https://??????.000webhostapp.com/api/insert.php'

    def meter():
        while True:
            requette = {'puissance': '+puissanceW+'}

            try:
              res = requests.post(adresse, data=requette)
              print(res.text)
            except:
              print "connection failed"
            break

    #sleep for desired amount of time
    if __name__ == "__main__":
         while True:
            meter()
            time.sleep(30)
```